# Codeigniter foreach works weird

Tags: codeigniter

Today I found my update function suddenly in codeigniter not working probaly. I solved this problem by calling the foreach loop twice here is my code:

```
function _update($options = array(),$set = array()) {
    ......
    foreach ($this->db->field_data($options['table']) as $field) {
        //never get inside this foreach loop, but if I removed this foreach loop it will not get inside the next foreach loop.
    }
    foreach ($this->db->field_data($options['table']) as $field) {
    if(isset($options[$field->name])) $this->db->where($field->name, $options[$field->name]);
    if(isset($set[$field->name])) $this->db->set($field->name, $set[$field->name]); 
    }
    ......
}
```

Is this problem cause by codeigniter or PHP?

Comment: Do you manipulate the array above this foreach? Could there be an internal pointer that needs to be reset?

Comment: need more code and clarification on what `not properly` means

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that $this->db->some_function returns the value, stopping from executing second if statement, to put simply: first loop stops after every $this->db->where iteration, while second loopreaches the set method. There's too little information for me about the problem, to try to help you further. More details please.

Comment: I got more detail on my question now. Could you please let me know what is the problem here?